# Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 80 Error

Tags: apache, linode

I have uploaded 2 django projects before and worked perfectly fine to the Linode server, but now for some reason I am receiving Error for 403 Port 80 error. I have revisited a tutorial word by word and revised it several times, I am not sure why I keep receving this error:

```
Error for 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 80
```

**Here is the config file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/ahesham/Portfolio/static
        <Directory /home/ahesham/Portfolio/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/ahesham/Portfolio/media
        <Directory /home/ahesham/Portfolio/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/ahesham/Portfolio/Portfolio>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ahesham/Portfolio/Portfolio/wsgi.py

        WSGIDaemonProcess Portfolio python-path=/home/ahesham/Portfolio python-home=/home/ahesham/Portfolio/venv

        WSGIProcessGroup Portfolio

</VirtualHost>
```

**In the error.log**

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

when i type ls -la

```
total 36
drwxr-x---  5 ahesham ahesham  4096 Aug  6 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root     4096 Aug  5 02:30 ..
-rw-------  1 ahesham ahesham  2115 Aug  7 02:20 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 ahesham ahesham   220 Aug  5 02:30 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 ahesham ahesham  3771 Aug  5 02:30 .bashrc
drwx------  3 ahesham ahesham  4096 Aug  6 12:53 .cache
drwxrwxr-x 10 ahesham www-data 4096 Aug  6 20:15 Portfolio
-rw-r--r--  1 ahesham ahesham   807 Aug  5 02:30 .profile
drwx------  2 ahesham ahesham  4096 Aug  5 02:41 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 ahesham ahesham     0 Aug  5 02:42 .sudo_as_admin_successful
```

when I try the project on an 8000 server it is woking perfectly fine other wise when I change the following commands: `sudo ufw delete allow 8000` `sudo ufw allow http/tcp` `sudo service apache2 restart`

**My question is what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?**

Please let me know if there are further information required to help assist fixing it

Comment: Please have a look in the apache logs and let us know what feedback it is giving. /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://serverfault.com.

Comment: @JordanCasey I have added the error from error.log

Answer (score 0):

type `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/`

`sudo cp 000-default.conf Portfolio.conf`
and add

```
    ServerName server_domain_name_or_IP
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm pretty sure you encountered the same issue as i did when follow Corey Schafer's Django tutorial on deploy django on linux server.

The issue was the permission settings on the Django project folder which Corey didn't mention in his video but if you run:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 ~/django_project/
```

This will fix the issue.

Credit to:

> [mod_wsgi - Permission denied - Unable to start Python home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730963/mod-wsgi-permission-denied-unable-to-start-python-home)

Answer (score 0):

I have two sites on my Apache server. One worked without problems. The second one worked, but only if I entered `https://webpage.com`. When I entered just `webpage.com` it didn't work. It was working before that. Maybe something went wrong after some update?

It was enough for me to enter:

```
a2ensite yourconfig.conf
service apache2 reload
```