# mod_wsgi - Permission denied - Unable to stat Python home

Tags: python-3.x, django, mod-wsgi

I am attempting to run django on an unmanaged VPS running Ubuntu 20.04.
I connected to the freshly installed server, installed Django and Postresql.
Apache was already installed. I then installed mod_wsgi.
I then attempted to configure my .conf file.
Edited file
`etc\apache2\sites-available\000-default.conf`
to include the following:

```
    Alias /static /root/django-apps/dmsemapping/staticfiles
    <Directory /root/django-apps/dmsemapping/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /root/django-apps/dmsemapping/dmsemapping>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess dmsemapping python-path=/root/django-apps/dmsemapping python-home=/root/django-apps/env
    WSGIProcessGroup dmsemapping
    WSGIScriptAlias / /root/django-apps/dmsemapping/dmsemapping/wsgi.py
```

`dmsemapping` is the name of my django project
`/root/django-apps/dmsemapping` is the path to my project
`/root/django-apps/env` is the path to my environment variable for python

When I run this I get a 403 error. In the error.log file I get:

```
Current thread 0x00007f84dde19c40 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
[Tue Oct 26 22:55:44.887129 2021] [wsgi:warn] [pid 12089:tid 140208634960960] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=12089): Unable to stat Python home /root/django-apps/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/root/django-apps/env'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/root/django-apps/env'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/root/django-apps/env'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/root/django-apps/env'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/root/django-apps/env'
  sys.path = [
    '/root/django-apps/env/lib/python38.zip',
    '/root/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8',
    '/root/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Any suggestions for what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're hosting Django on disk as the `root` superuser - it is a really bad idea from a security perspective. I'd recommend using a service user. Then you can pass that user and group to `WSGIDaemonProcess ... user=your_user group=your_group`.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the same problem by changing the permission of myuser's folder

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/<user>
```

Actually, it is from here:https://www.linode.com/community/questions/22951/no-python-frame-error-while-trying-to-connect-to-apache-on-mod_wsgi-in-ubuntu

Comment: It worked for me too. It will work if your project is inside ```/home/<user>/<project?>```. Not sure tho.

Comment: why the /home/user has to do with it?